# Finding a third solution from two other solutions for linear ODE not equal to 0

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Edit: **I am not asking how to solve the differential equation below.** I know how to solve the equation as it is extremely easy. What I am asking is this:

For the equation $y' + y = 0$, if you already have the solutions $y_1, y_2$, then the solution $y_3 = c_1y_1 + c_2y_2$ where $c_1,c_2$ are any constants.

However, if that equation is modified to be $y' + y = 4$ for instance, then it doesn't look like you can find $y_3$ by taking any linear combination of $y_1,y_2$. It looks like you would need a specific linear combination, and I'd like to know how you would find that as I seem to be missing something.

In short, what constants $c_1, c_2$ would make $y_3 = c_1y_1 + c_2y_2$ a solution of that equation.

Also to whoever downvoted me: Seriously? Why are you people so obsessed with downvoting simple questions? I'm not asking for you to solve my homework or how to add 1+1. Why would you downvote me for trying to clarify something?

Comment: If $y'(x)+y(x)=4$ then what ODE does $ay(x)$ solve for constant, a?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to a linear inhomogeneous ODE (inhomogeneous means zero is not a solution, or equivalently, there's a term with no $y$-dependence) is the sum of two parts, the *complementary function* $y_c$, which solves the homogeneous equation, and the *particular integral* $y_p$, which is one solution to the inhomogeneous equation. The complementary function is a sum $\sum_i A_i y_i$, and the constants $A_i$ are arbitrary unless determined by some set of boundary conditions, but the particular integral is fixed (at least up to adding bits of the complementary function to it).

---

This is exactly analogous to solving the inhomogeneous matrix equation
$$ Ax = b, $$
where the homogeneous equation $Ax=0$ has nonzero solutions: the general solution is the sum of a particular solution to $Ax=b$ and an arbitrary sum of solutions to the homogeneous equation.

Answer (score 0):

When an equation is non-homogenous, then there is a particular solution $y_p(x)$ that ensures the left side always equals the right side. This particular solution is decided by the equation and doesn't have a constant multiplier.

In your case, $y' + y = 4$, the particular solution is pretty clear. Try $y = 4$, and the left side equals the right side. So, a solution to the DE is $y = 4$.

Of course, that's not the most general solution. Notice that $y = Ce^{-x} + 4$ is the most general solution. That extra term comes from $y' + y = 0$. Since the DE is of order 1, there is one constant.